# UWP Bluetooth: issues with DeviceWatcher and findAllAsync()

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, uwp, winjs

I wanted to get Bluetooth devices using UWP. I really want to use `Devicewatcher` as I should be continued looking for new devices.

The result I get in `Added` event of the `DeviceWatcher` is `DeviceInformation` and does not have all the properties I need in my app, hence I should be calling something to get the `BluetoothDevice` object. The problem is when I call the following methods with the `Device.ID` that I got from `DeviceWatcher` have different errors:

- `BluetoothDevice.fromBluetoothAddressAsync()` with device ID the `done` method is never called.
- `BluetoothDevice.fromIdAsync()` raises an *Element not Found* error.

As I read in another post, I also tried getting the devices from `DeviceInformation.findAllAsync()` all calling both the above methods but same result. ([winjs-and-bluetooth-connection-error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85171406-8b07-4352-a48a-7f30d4179138/winjs-and-bluetooth-connection-error?forum=peertopeer))

Can Anyone suggest what the issue is or another approach? My Codes are as below.

#### Code to create watcher:

```
ondeviceadd = function (args) {
    //my code here
};
deviceWatch = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.createWatcher(selector, null);
deviceWatch.addEventListener("added", ondeviceadd);
deviceWatch.addEventListener("removed", ondeviceRemove);
deviceWatch.addEventListener("updated", ondeviceUpdate);
deviceWatch.addEventListener("stopped", onStopped);
deviceWatch.addEventListener("enumerationcompleted", ondeviceComplete);
deviceWatch.start();
```

#### Code to get device from findAllAsync:

```
var selector = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getDeviceSelector();
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(selector, null).done(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //My code here
    }
});
```

#### Code to get BluetoothDevice:

```
Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.fromBluetoothAddressAsync(devid).done(
function(devinfo) {
    res = devinfo;
})
Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.fromIdAsync(data.id).done(function(result){
    //my code here
});
Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.fromIdAsync(devId).done(function (result) {    
    //my code here
})
```

Comment: "_As I read in another post,_"...what is that post? Please edit the question to link that text to the post...

Comment: Added the link to other another post.

Answer (score 0):

[BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync | fromIdAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.fromidasync.aspx) is the right method to get the [BluetoothDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.aspx) object with the given Device Id. And in [DeviceWatcher.Added | added event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.added.aspx), we can get the [DeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation) object which contains [DeviceInformation.Id | id property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.id.aspx) but no Bluetooth Address info. So [BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync | fromBluetoothAddressAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.frombluetoothaddressasync) can't be used here.

However while using `BluetoothDevice.fromIdAsync` method, we need note that this method needs **bluetooth** capability. See **Requirements** → **Capabilities** and also [Device capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#device-capabilities). So to use this method, we need add **Bluetooth** Capability in ***Package.appxmanifest*** like:[image]

And then when we first call this method, the system will request user to give permission to access the Bluetooth device. If the user chooses **Yes**, this method will return a `BluetoothDevice` object represents the device. But if the use chooses **No** then this method will return `null`.

Comment: I will give it a shot today. But I really want to use DeviceWatcher because I need to continuously watch for the Bluetooth devices turn on or made discoverable after the process is started. I think if I could get some way to get the device from devicewatcher and then create the bluetoothdevice.fromIDAsync then it could  be a perfect solution.

Comment: @PriyankC You can use `DeviceWatcher` with `BluetoothDevice.fromIdAsync` method. I've tested it and it worked well.

Comment: Hi @PriyankC, any update? Did my answer solve your problem? Is it an [acceptable answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?